# How to write OR in between line in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-text

Hi everyone I am new to flutter and trying to write `OR` in a horizontal line like shown in figure but I do not know how to do that, I have tried to google it but that did not helped me
[example demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAVKh.png)

**Note:** OR is in center

Comment: Row widget, expanded widget with a line, add some horizontal padding for your Text, add another expanded widget with a line.

Comment: How to add that line? Will Divider help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the solution using a row widget

```
Row(children: const [
                Expanded(child: Divider(thickness: 1.5)),
                Text("OR",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey)),
                Expanded(child: Divider(thickness: 1.5)),
              ]),
```

This is it when i tried to create Instagram login screen

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try below Code hope its help to you. You must use this(-- OR -- ) type of design **Expanded** or **Flexible** Widget

Go [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) For **Expanded** Widget and [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) for **Flexible** Widget

```
  Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('OR'),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Your result Screen like -> [image]